# sql server: get result based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: screenshot]

As shown above I have values in my table.

The result expected here is to show `id` and `col1` data which only has `col2` `0`. For example, for `id 123` and `col1 1` the `col2` is `1` as well as `0` therefore the record should not be part of result but `122` will be as its all record has `col2` value `0` only. Also `id` along with `col1` are unique so `124 1` will not be part of result whereas `124  2` will be.

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.  (2) Put sample data and desired results in the question as a table.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You filled out a box which said "ask a question". Questions in English are denoted by a question mark, ?, and can receive an answer. Please [edit] the post to contain an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

```
SELECT id,col1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id,col1
HAVING SUM(CAST(col2 AS INT)) = 0
```

Results:

```
+----------------------+
|   id    |   col1     |
-----------------------
|  122    |    1       |
|  124    |    2       |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: That query works but col2 column is bit and we can't perform sum operation on that. Would you suggest something else?

Comment: Great thnx for that.